# SSRL Expression throwing error

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

if a value is 0 then 0 else run the switch statement 
 it returns Nil regardless. please help

```
    =IIf(Fields!SpecialOvtHrs.Value>0,IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="OMR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.000"),
IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="BHD",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.000"),
IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="AED",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="KWD",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value *1,"#,##0.000"),
IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="JOD",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="QAR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
IIf(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="SAR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),"Nill"))))))),"Nill")


=Switch(Fields!SpecialOvtHrs.Value=0,0,
```

Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="OMR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.000"),

Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="OMR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.000"),
                                                Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="BHD",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.000"),
                                                Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="AED",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.00"),
                                                Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="KWD",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*1,"#,##0.000"),
                                                Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="JOD",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.00"),
                                                Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="QAR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.00"),
                                                Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="SAR",Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value,"#,##0.00")).

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. It's better to set the formatting code in the value textbox property. 2. Try using `SWITCH` instead of nested `IIF`.   These will make your expression more simple and easier to debug. Also please provide some sample values of your data

Comment: i have updated the code and included the switch statement but it still remains the same. sample values will be any integer 0,5000, etc

Comment: The suggestion is to make your code easier to read, not to solve your problem. As I have mentioned providing some data could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following SWITCH statement.

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!SpecialOvtHrs.Value <=0 , "Nill",
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="OMR", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.000"),
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="BHD", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.000"),
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="AED", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="KWD", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value *1,"#,##0.000"),
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="JOD", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="QAR", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
    Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value="SAR", Format(Fields!OvtPay.Value*Fields!ExchangeRate.Value / Fields!OvtHrs.Value,"#,##0.00"),
    True, "No match")
```

Other (optional) things to consider..

- Store the number of minor units against you currencies in the database (e.g. 3 for 'OMR').
- Store an exchange rate of 1 against your local currency 'KWD', this way you can use the same calculation for all instances and you won't need to format it at that point.
- Use the minor units in the format property of the cell like `="n" & Fields!MinorUnits.Value` this would result in 'n3' for OMR for instance)

Comment: basically i wanted to remove the zero because it will throw an error while dividing by zero

Comment: Its easier to read than a bunch of IIF's and iwth IIF SSRS evaluates every part of the expression, with SWITCH it stops as soon as it hit a match (hence the last bit that will display "NO match" if all the above are not matched. It's also more flexible if you take on board my points to consider as you can shorten it to 3 lines by only checking if the value is less than 0 and if not doing a simple calculation with no formatting. Divide by zero should not occur as the later expressions will not be evaluated.

Comment: Alan that will make code easier to read and debug. It doesn't mean that it's the solution to the problem but it's more a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have a sample of your data I ll assume that there is no match in the cfgCurrencySymbol.Value.

Case matters when you make string checks so either use the correct case or upper case the field values like below

```
UCase(Fields!cfgCurrencySymbol.Value) = "OMR"
```